# How to extract image from CCSprite in Cococ2d v2.1

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-2.x

I am extracting an image from a CCSprite in Cocos2d v2.1. I have gotten the reference of extracted image, but it's blank.

Code is as follows:

```
CCSprite *tile=[grass tileAt:CGPointMake(4 ,18 )];

int tx = tile.contentSize.width;
int ty = tile.contentSize.height;

CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty];

[sprite setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];

[renderer begin];
[sprite visit];
[renderer end];

UIImage *img=[renderer getUIImageFromBuffer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CCRenderTexture *renderer = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:tx height:ty pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888 depthStencilFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8];

    [renderer beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0 depth:1.0f];
    [sprite visit];
    [renderer end];
    UIImage *img = [renderer getUIImage];
```